# Batch file for replacing text, or writing it if it's not there

Tags: batch-file, ini

Good morning,

I'm having an issue trying to figure out how to approach a project that I'm working on...

Basically what's happening is I'm needing to go into a text file, look for a certain string of text, (I.E. ColumnSeparator=Y) and changing it to ColumnSeparator=N.
If "ColumnSeparator=Y/N" doesn't exist, I need to write ~4-5 lines of text to add the section of text into the file. Appending is fine.

Now, this is the tricky part. This file I'm editing, is a configuration for a file for a program that is used on ~850 machines, and every file is a little different, and depending on Window XP vs Windows 7, they are located in 2 different places.
In Windows 7 it's located in: `C:\AS400\s10138fd.ws` but in Windows XP it's located in: `C:\Program Files\IBM\Client Access\Emulator\Private\AS400.ws`

Any ideas??

Thanks!!

Here is the *.ws file information I need to edit:

```
[Profile]
ID=WS
Description=
Version=9
[Translation]
IBMDefaultView=Y
DefaultView=
IBMDefaultDBCS=Y
DefaultDBCS=
[Communication]
AutoConnect=Y
Link=telnet5250
Session=5250
ForceConfigPanel=N
[Telnet5250]
HostName=S10138fd
Security=Y
HostPortNumber=992
SSLClientAuthentication=Y
CertSelection=AUTOSELECT
AutoReconnect=Y
[5250]
HostCodePage=037-U
PrinterType=IBM3812
[Keyboard]
CuaKeyboard=2
Language=United-States
IBMDefaultKeyboard=N
DefaultKeyboard=C:\AS400\AS400.KMP
[LastExitView]
A=4 1335 -14 896 609 3 13 29 400 0 IBM3270� 37
```

I need to add:

```
[Window]
ViewFlags=CE00
RuleLinePos=0 0
ColumnSeparator=N
```

Here is the new script:

```
if exist "c:\as400\s10138fd.ws" (cd \as400)

copy s10138fd.ws temp.ws
echo [Window]>s10138fd.ws
echo ViewFlags=CE00>>s10138fd.ws
echo RuleLinePos=0 0>>s10138fd.ws
echo ColumnSeparator=N>>s10138fd.ws
type temp.ws >>s10138fd.ws
del temp.ws

) ELSE (cd\program files\ibm\client access\emulator\private)

copy as400.ws temp.ws
echo [Window]>as400.ws
echo ViewFlags=CE00>>as400.ws
echo RuleLinePos=0 0>>as400.ws
echo ColumnSeparator=N>>as400.ws
type temp.ws >>as400.ws
del temp.ws
)
pause
```

Comment: If you know JScript (an ecmascript dialect like javascript) you could do this really easy using a hybrid batchscript (a polyglot file containing both batchscript AND JScript). Would that be an option? It would work from windows 95 to windows 8 without dependency's other then having IE installed.

Comment: Add the 4 or 5 lines WHERE in the file? Just at the end?

Comment: You might try cscript instead of a batch file. I find JScript easier to work with. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hww8txat(v=vs.84).aspx

Comment: that's how hybrid's work (using cscript) but without the mess so to the os it seems a normal app. Also, apart from *where* the text will be edited, how large will the files be? So we know if we'd need to use stream methods or simply load the files in memory and perform work there.

Comment: I'm new to scripting actually...This is one of my first projects and it's a sink or swim kind of situation...@PeterWright Yes, I can ammend them to the end of the file, but if the information (ColumnSeparator=Y) is listed before the newly written text, it will reference the first section and ignore the second. If that makes sense...

Comment: 'section'... hmm, could the file(s) be a regular ini-file? If so, you might want to google 'batchscript ini file'. Could you post a sample, especially the case of adding lines?

Comment: Thank you for adding the requested samples. I took the liberty of cleaning them up and adding the other relevant info you provided in your comments. I also provided my hybrid solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the new script that I was able to get working!!!

```
c:
cd \as400
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in ('dir /b/s/a-d *.ws') do ( 
copy %%x temp.txt
del %%x
Echo [Window]>%%x
Echo ViewFlags=CE00>>%%x
Echo RuleLinePos=0 0 >>%%x
Echo ColumnSeparator=N>>%%x
type temp.txt>>%%x
del temp.txt
)
else (
c:
cd \users
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in ('dir /b/s/a-d *.ws') do ( 
copy %%x temp.txt
del %%x
Echo [Window]>%%x
Echo ViewFlags=CE00>>%%x
Echo RuleLinePos=0 0 >>%%x
Echo ColumnSeparator=N>>%%x
type temp.txt>>%%x
)
else (
c:
cd \"Documents and Settings"
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in ('dir /b/s/a-d *.ws') do ( 
copy %%x temp.txt
del %%x
Echo [Window]>%%x
Echo ViewFlags=CE00>>%%x
Echo RuleLinePos=0 0 >>%%x
Echo ColumnSeparator=N>>%%x
type temp.txt>>%%x
del temp.txt
)
```

Comment: Ah, no wonder other answers erred "file not found", in your script you point at `c:\users` and `c:\documents and settings` instead of `C:\Program Files\IBM\Client Access\Emulator\Private` (besides that you now process any `*.ws` file you find in each directory). Also note that in the script you currently posted you do not delete your `temp.txt` in `c:\users`. Lastly, I assume you know this script does *not* search for a string and conditionally updates or appends a section to the file (as you specified); it just blindly prepends a section to your file. Just as a well intended cautionary note!

Comment: sorry, can't help myself, must post this to: Given your description in your question and comments, you should realize *not* all config/ini -'parsers' will parse the files in the same way. Some will err if they find 2 identical sections and/or key's, other will use the first they find, others use the last they find. Be sure to check the documentation (or thoroughly test) how this 'as400' thing reacts to duplicate (contradicting `Y` vs `N`) directives/entry's !!

Comment: It reads the first Y/N statement and that's the one it uses. It can have Y 10 times below it, but as long as it reads N first, it doesn't make a difference :)

Comment: Great, I would have felt a jerk if I hadn't pointed that one out.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you don't need to know the original value of ColumnSeparator, just reset it to N.

Use the following code to save a copy of the config file without the ColumnSeparator data, where configfile is the config file:

```
type configfile | find /v "ColumnSeparator" > configfile.tmp
```

Then use a simple echo and redirect to append the ColumnSeparator value to the end of the file.

```
echo ColumnSeparator=N >> configfile.tmp
```

You can then delete the old config file, and rename the newly created one (configfile.tmp) to replace the old one...

---

Here is the updated script:

```
type configfile | find /v "[Window]" | find /v "ViewFlags" | find /v "RuleLinePos" | find /v "ColumnSeparator">configfile.tmp

echo [Window]>>configfile.tmp
echo ViewFlags=CE00>>configfile.tmp
echo RuleLinePos=0 0>>configfile.tmp
echo ColumnSeparator=N>>configfile.tmp
```

That should work, though it needs to be in a script that would find the desired config file. The `find /v` command filters out the line that include the desired string.

---

Again updated... (Again)

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
systeminfo | find "OS Name">temp.tmp
for %%a in ('findstr "7" temp.tmp') do set ver=7
if "%ver%" == "7" (
    set file=s10138fd.ws
    set path=C:\AS400\
    )
for %%a in ('findstr "XP" temp.tmp') do set ver=xp
if "%ver%" == "xp" (
    set file=AS400.ws
    set path=C:\Program Files\IBM\Client Access\Emulator\Private\
    )
del temp.tmp
goto find

:find
if not exist "%path%%file%" (
    echo config file does not exist!
    goto end
    )
echo config file exists!
echo proceeding to fix...
goto dumper

:dumper
cd "%path%"
type %file% | find /v "[Window]" | find /v "ViewFlags" | find /v "RuleLinePos" | find /v "ColumnSeparator">configfile.tmp
echo [Window]>>configfile.tmp
echo ViewFlags=CE00>>configfile.tmp
echo RuleLinePos=00>>configfile.tmp
echo ColumnSeparator=N>>configfile.tmp
ren %file% %file%.bk
ren configfile.tmp %file%
echo fixed!
goto end

:end
exit
```

Comment: If you post the two possible locations of the config file, i could finish this batch up for you...

Comment: if the value doesn't exist in the file, I need to append:

[Window]
ViewFlags=CE00
RuleLinePos=0 0
ColumnSeparator=N

To the bottom of the file. If that chunk of text exists, I need to change ColumnSeparator=Y to N.

Comment: The text stacks on itself, it's not in a single line like this...

Also, the file that is being edited has different configurations for every user. If I were to make one config and use it for everyone, they would lose all of their settings, sadly.

Comment: You would need to run the batch on every computer, but it would preserve their individual settings and allow you to alter the config file.

Comment: Could you post a copy of the config file?

Comment: Sure, I can post it. How do I post it here?

Comment: The file is in 2 separate locations on the machine depending on windows version. It's either: AS400.ws or s10138fd.ws

Comment: Ok, so, I did some testing on some machines. I was able to manually add these lines of text to the top of .ws file and it did not effect any other facets of the program, except it did fix what I needed fixed. So I guess what I'm looking for is a batch script to find a specific file, and add 4 strings of text to the top of the file and save it. Does that sound like something reasonable or is it complex? Thanks everyone for you help, it's very, very much appreciated.

Comment: To post a copy of the config file, just copy the text in it and add it to your question...

Comment: What are that paths to the config files, and what are their respective versions? I don't think that you can append to the beginning of a file, but if you use the 'find /v' method, you can remove the all of the lines that store any of the values you want to set, and then you can add those lines at the end of the file. If run on each machine, this would preserve the initial settings stored in the file except for the ones you want to change, those would be removed... You could then easily append the corrected lines to the end of the file...

Comment: The file is located in 2 different spots. Windows 7 it's located in:
C:\AS400\s10138fd.ws

In Windows XP it's located in:
C:\Program Files\IBM\Client Access\Emulator\Private\AS400.ws

Comment: All right, i modified my answer to have the full script... It might need modifying, but it represents a pretty close idea.

Comment: That looks fantastic. Thank you so much for your help. One question, and it might sound stupid... Where do I run the batch from? It gets half way through then says "config file does not exist"

Comment: @user2232429: Let me take another look at the code and check it, as that's a message i wrote into the batch that's displayed when it can't find the config file... Are you testing it on a XP or 7 box?

Comment: I can test on either or. The current testing was done on a 7 box (Mine)

Comment: @user2232429: Alright, try this version of the script. If it works, post a copy of the edited config file. Do you want a full-batch implementation, or just something that works?

Comment: @GitaarLAB: As your script is much more advanced then mine, would you mind looking over my code and telling me what you think. Any thoughts would be very helpful in my plight to further my understanding of computers.

Comment: Thx! I don't have `systeminfo` on w2k (haven't checked others). Alternatively you could do the same thing with `ver` (searching for '5', '5.1', '6', etc). But that has the known drawback where it sometimes does not work reliably on localized versions. Other then that, it *looks* ok. Since I know of the hybrid (the construct is actually my own, never seen this one in the wild, only (deliberate?) erroneous variations), I embrace the simplicity/power of the command-line equivalent/counterpart of HTA. My hybrid is also *fully* within spec from win95 to win8 (according to the documentations).

Comment: @GitaarLAB: Thanks for the feedback! A problem I've also had with the 'systeminfo' method (which i include in my other os-specific scripts) is on machines that have been "optimized" which includes turning of the systeminfo service... Do you like win2k better than xp or 7?

Comment: One thing I remember tough from reading your previous code last night where you used the double ampersand `&&` command separator and was thinking to comment you with this hint: *`&&` may not run the commands to the right of `&&` command. This behavior occurs because the && command separator performs error checking. If the command to the left of the && command does not return the expected results, the commands to the right of the && command do not run. Solution: use a single `&`.*   SRC: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/279253     Other then that, it looks like a clever batchscript

Comment: @GitaarLAB: Thanks! I didn't know that && was used for error checking... I'll use & next time. I was trying to have the script set the path and file variables without having to have an if block, but i don't think that the 'for' loop can do more than one operation...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27598/discussion-between-gitaarlab-and-user1)

Answer (score 2):

So actually you just want to conditionally update a plain simple INI-file with a batch-script.

I'm guessing you need this to be a single-file solution, otherwise (in your batchscript) you probably would have used something like :

- iniman.exe from [MS 2003 reskit](http://download.microsoft.com/download/8/e/c/8ec3a7d8-05b4-440a-a71e-ca3ee25fe057/rktools.exe) (.NET console, does *not* work on PE)
- [inifile](http://www.horstmuc.de/wbat32.htm#inifile)  (or any other of the abundantly available command-line ini-tools)
- [NirCmd](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/)
- [other scripting solutions](http://blogs.technet.com/b/deploymentguys/archive/2010/07/15/reading-and-modifying-ini-files-with-scripts.aspx)

To do exactly as you have currently specified, I created the following *hybrid* (Batch/JScript) for you
(using ONE file, and NO temp-file):

```
@if (0)==(1) REM BatchScript: 
:INIT
 @ECHO OFF & CLS
:MAIN
 cscript //NoLogo //E:JScript "%~f0"
 GOTO ENDBAT
:ENDBAT
 ECHO        Press any key to exit...&PAUSE>NUL
 GOTO :EOF
@end // JScript:

 var TRG = ['C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\Client Access\\Emulator\\Private\\AS400.ws',
            'C:\\AS400\\s10138fd.ws'
           ],
     rxp = /ColumnSeparator=[YN]/i,
     rep = 'ColumnSeparator=N',
     add = ['[Window]',
            'ViewFlags=CE00',
            'RuleLinePos=0 0',
            'ColumnSeparator=N',
            ''  //empty line
           ].join('\r\n'),

     WSO = WScript.stdout,
     FSO = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject"),
                                 ForReading=1, ForWriting=2,
       L = TRG.length, ret = '', flg = 1, HND;


 while(L--){
    if( FSO.FileExists(TRG[L]) ){ TRG = TRG[L]; L = ''; break; }
 } 

 if(L === ''){
    WSO.write('FOUND: '+TRG+'\r\nWorking...\r\n');
    HND=FSO.OpenTextFile(TRG, ForReading);
    while(!HND.AtEndOfStream){
       L=HND.ReadLine();
       if( rxp.test(L) ){ L = L.replace(rxp,rep); flg = 0; }
       ret+= L+'\r\n';
    }  HND.Close();

    if(flg){ ret= ret.replace(/(\r\n)*$/,'\r\n')+add; }

    HND=FSO.OpenTextFile(TRG, ForWriting);
    HND.Write(ret);  HND.Close();

    WSO.write('\r\nDONE!!!\r\n');
 } else {
    WSO.write('ERROR: no file found\r\n');
 }
```

**Note:**

- Don't forget empty line at the end of the script (to be sure) and name it '`yourExtCommand.bat`'.
- This script is thoroughly tested (including JSLint) on W98, W2k, XP/2003, Vista and Windows 7 (not yet 8, but who uses that anyway..) and it works like a charm!
- This script uses the the location of the ini-file itself as your 'os-detection', since you specified:
  '*Windows 7 it's located in: C:\AS400\s10138fd.ws In Windows XP it's located in: C:\Program Files\IBM\Client Access\Emulator\Private\AS400.ws*'
  and as such it will update the first file it finds (which should be the only file on the system) *starting with win7 ('cleverly' avoiding unnecessary access to the protected %programfiles% dir and triggering UAC)*.
- Also changing 'ColumnSeparator=N' to 'ColumnSeparator=N' wouldn't be a problem right?
  The script does this for simplicity, since you specified: '*If "ColumnSeparator=Y/N" doesn't exist, I need to write ~4-5 lines of text to add the section of text into the file*', '*append them to the end of the file*' and '*look for a certain string of text, (I.E. ColumnSeparator=Y) and changing it to ColumnSeparator=N*'
- REM/delete the full `...Press any key to...` line to make it run unattended.
- Updated script to handle trailing blank lines smartly, giving control over them via the `add` variable.
- If you want a blank line before the added section, change line  `add = ['[Window]',`
  to  `add = ['', '[Window]',` (for example)

---

Lastly I'd like to note (partially for myself) that [apparently](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/Scripting/Shell/Batch/Q_26696202.html) one can use `inf` files to update/modify ini-files using:

- `RUNDLL32.EXE SETUPAPI.DLL,InstallHinfSection DefaultInstall 128
  c:\temp\test.inf`    (said to be 'better'?)

or

- `RUNDLL32 SETUPX.DLL,LaunchHinfSection DefaultInstall 132 test.inf`

(both called from the batch-script).

The inf-file could also be echoed or written from the batchscript / JScript / VBScript.

Those inf-files could look like:

```
[version]
signature="$CHICAGO$"


[DefaultInstall]
UpdateInis=IniVal


[IniVal]
"C:\temp\whatever.ini",YourSection,"Something=OldValue","Something=NewValue",0
```

or:

```
[Version]
Signature="$CHICAGO$"

[DefaultInstall]
UpdateINIs=Sys.Ini

[Sys.Ini]
System.ini,ReplaceMeWithAppropriateSection,,”MinPs=32”
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Holy cr@p Gitaar. What would I have done without you guys. I tried for at least a month to figure this stuff out (ZERO scripting knowledge and my boss said 'here, do this have fun' and sent me on my way). You guys really came through for me. One thing to note @GitaarLAB for some reason when this script writes the text into the file, there is an extra blank line added before the text, and I think it's causing the file to not register the change... Thoughts?

Comment: **Please tell me one thing first, did this work on win7?**    About the blank line: See this line: `sec = ['', '[Window]',` and change it to: `sec = ['[Window]',`. Tada, blank line gone.    About 'registering': either you need a restart OR.. this 'AS400' reads its settings on start and writes them back to the ini-file when 'AS400' exits/closes (because of windows shutdown/reboot). Test that.    PS: there is one catch to this script.. passing this off as 'your own' could be difficult if you can't you explain this to your boss (given that you couldn't remove the trailing blank line..).

Comment: Alright guys - I seem to be running into errors, or files not existing mid script... I created my own script, and added it to my question. can you guys take a look at it and see if it will do what I need it to do, and if I have misplaced characters...etc? I'm being proactive and trying my hand at it whole heartedly!

Comment: ***Did my script work in win7?* What is wrong with the current answers?** I updated my script to handle trailing blank lines simpler. The script you added to your question doesn't do at all what you told us you wanted it to do. It generally tries to prepend a section, without even checking if it (or parts of it) already exists. Also the if-blocks `()` seem double-closed. And you are forcing the script to be run from the root `c:\`. Should you intend to put it in autoexec.bat, know that from w2k upward you need to tell windows to actually use/execute that file (it doesn't do that by default).

Comment: The script you wrote wont run in Win7, at least not on my machine or the other I tested with. "File does not exist". I also need to be able to explain line for line what is happening with the script and what it's doing. @GitaarLAB your script is WAY over my head...

Comment: So your first comment (about the blank line) was after you tested the script in XP? Is "File does not exist" the *exact* error-message? Did your own script also give a "file does not exist" message? Did you check if the file does exist? (Especially since you have reported quite often that some file did not exist) Did you run the script as admin or as user? What are the user-permissions, what are the file-permissions? Is the file read-only? Is the virus-scanner enabled? Is win7 64 bit? Is `Scrrun.dll` correctly installed and enabled (in registry)? Must it be a single script, without extra tool?

Comment: I updated my answer because I found that `new ActiveXObject` is only supported in IE (although a multitude of MS documentation/examples uses it in WSH anyway and it works in w2k/xp/?) ([source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7sw4ddf8%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)). Could you test it again please? If it fails again, run `regsvr32 "c:\windows\system32\scrrun.dll"`. Else, check registry: see [1](http://xsisupport.com/2011/10/20/activex-component-cant-create-object-scripting-filesystemobject/) and [2](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ITCG/thread/0511c9d4-9e92-4f2c-baf7-5428d3b2d44c/)

Comment: Hey sorry for the late response. It turns out that my script worked. I tried to think overly-simplified when writing it and it did the trick! Yes the file exists, Ran it as Admin, FC file/folder permissions, Not read-only, Virus Scanner is disabled, 32-bit, Yes it's installed and active, and yes it needs to be a single script.

Comment: (apart from me wondering if my updated script also works) I think it's great your script works. Since the script you appended to your question contains errors and it does *not* check if `ColumnSeparator` exists (see my comment above), you might want to post (and accept) your new script as answer.

Comment: Had a chance to test my hybrid in w98, w2k, xp/2003, vista **and windows 7** (not yet 8, but who uses that anyway..) and it works like a charm!